# Не вызвается деструктор касса Qt Widget

Tags: c++, qt

Есть 2 класса виджетов. Я хотел сделать так, что при нажатии кнопки, виджет на котором я сейчас нахожусь удалился и открыл мне новый класс с виджетом.
      Проблема в том, что деструктор Logwindow в консоль не выводит, и как я понимаю удаление не происходит. Пробовал использовать и deleteLater() метод, но не знаю как проверить освобождение памяти с ним. Вот код:

Loginwindow.cpp:

```
Logwindow::Logwindow(QWidget *parent):
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::loginwindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->pas_edit->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);

    connect(ui->reg_button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Logwindow::customSignal);
    connect(ui->log_button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Logwindow::loginSignal);
}
Logwindow::~Logwindow()
{
    std::cout << "Delete Logwindow";
}
```

Logwindow.hpp:

```
namespace Ui 
{
    class Loginwindow;
}

class Logwindow:public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Logwindow(const QString &text, QWidget *parent=Q_NULLPTR);
    ~Logwindow();

signals:
    void customSignal();
    void loginSignal();

private:
    Ui::loginwindow *ui;
};
```

Regwindow.h:

```
namespace Ui 
{
    class Regwindow;
}

class Regwindow:public QWidget
{
public:
   explicit Regwindow(QWidget *parent=Q_NULLPTR);
private:
    QLabel *label;
    Ui::regwindow *ui;
};
```

Regwindow.cpp:

```
Regwindow::Regwindow(QWidget *parent):
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::regwindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->r_passEdit->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
    ui->r_secpassEdit->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);  

    Logwindow *log = new Logwindow("LogWindow");
    Regwindow *reg;

    QObject::connect(log, &Logwindow::customSignal, [&reg, &log](){
        reg = new Regwindow();
        reg->show();
        log->~Logwindow();
});

    log->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, с endl теперь выводится. Почитал про явный вызов деструктора и последую вашему совету, использовав delete.

Comment: Создал канонический вопрос на тему буферизации потоков ввода-вывода в C++: [std::cout не выводит данные в консоль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/743030/208074).

Comment: @Arhad, может оформите ответом, чтобы не висел не отвеченный вопрос?

Comment: @ixSci, сделано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Строка `log->~Logwindow();` выглядит очень странно. Не надо вызывать деструктор явно, оставляя при этом «висящую» область памяти. Удаляйте полноценно, через `delete` — он сам неявно вызывает деструктор.
2. Обязательно посылайте в консоль `std::endl`. Содержимое `std::cout` [кэшируется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/743030/208074), и потому вывод может отсутствовать из-за отсутствия команды на сброс этого кэша (чем `endl` и занимается).