# std::cout не выводит данные в консоль

Tags: c++, потоки-данных

У меня есть код, который выводит в консоль некоторый текст:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!";

    // Обеспечим некоторую задержку, не давая приложению завершиться
    pause();

    return 0;
}
```

Однако текст не выводится, пока приложение не завершится штатным образом (в данном случае при сигнале).

В чём дело?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вы столкнулись с таким явлением, как *буферизация* потоков ввода-вывода.

Дело в том, что в C++ потоки [`std::istream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/) и [`std::ostream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/) (и, сответственно, их потомки) — это всего лишь обёртки над побайтовым буфером [`std::streambuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/). Сам же `std::streambuf` содержит в себе два кэша — один для чтения, другой для записи, — в виде массивов, описываемых границами и курсором (то есть текущей позицией):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*<sup>Источник: [Frank B. Brokken. C++ Annotations Version 10.8.1. Chapter 14: Polymorphism](http://www.icce.rug.nl/documents/cplusplus/cplusplus14.html)</sup>*

При любой работе с данными класс буфера сначала пытается сделать всё в рамках этого кэша. И только если это не является возможным (переполнился буфер записи, либо исчерпался буфер чтения), он обращается к своему дочернему классу-реализации конкретного буфера и просит либо опустошить буфер записи, либо загрузить новые данные для чтения (через вызов чисто виртуальных методов `overflow()` и `underflow()` соответственно).

В вашем случае очистка кэша срабатывала исключительно при уничтожении `std::streambuf`, ассоциированного со стандартным потоком вывода (так как длина записанной строки была недостаточной для переполнения кэша). Соответственно, для немедленного вывода данных необходимо сбросить буфер записи вручную, вызовом метода `std::ostream::flush()`. Кстати, этот метод неявно вызывается при использовании `std::endl`.