# Не выводит cout

Tags: c++, вывод

Уже 30 минут сижу и не понимаю почему выводит только cout, который выводит вектор. Пытался еще другие cout прописать,  гуглил, но все тщетно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    std::vector <int> nums;
    int in = 0, max = 0, min = 1000; 

    while (std::cin >> in) {
        nums.push_back(in);
    }

    for (int i : nums) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
        if (max<i) {
            max = i;
        }
        if (min > i) {
            min = i;
        }
            std::cout << "Наибольшее значение равно: " << max
              << "\nНаименьшее значение равно: " << min;
            //вот этот cout почему то не выводит
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/PXX3wk — что здесь не так, что выводит?...

Comment: `<< std::endl`?

Comment: Кстати, что вы понимаете под "не выводит"? А то, может, имеется в виду что "не выводит" — это выводит на каждой итерации, а не один раз?

Comment: в консоль выводится только вектор, а вот max и min из конца программы не выводятся.

Comment: По указанной ссылке смотрели?

Comment: Всё прекрасно выводит - https://godbolt.org/z/Ehhn8jj4f . Вот только у вас это выводит в цикле, переместите фигурную закрывающую скобку цикла вверх, до cout. Тогда выведется один раз в конце

Comment: @ComeInRage странно я запускал программу в визуалке и почему-то у меня выводит только и вектор. И да я знаю что cout в цикле, изначально он был вне цикла в самом конце программы, но когда я обнаружил что мин и макс не выводит, начал эту строчку таскать по всей программе надеясь на изменения

Comment: Может быть проблема в том, как я завершаю ввод данных в цикле? Можете сказать как вы завершаете ввод в Visual Studio?

Comment: `.. << std :: flush ;` - покажет всё, что осталось в буфере.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/743030/312941

Comment: ¿Может вы вообще на завершаете ввод? ¿Функция main у вас возвращается? ¿Или вы остановились на какой-то итерации цикла и жалуетесь, что не видите вывода `std::cout << "Наибольшее значение равно: " << max` в консоли на каждой итерации цикла? Так это у вас неправильные ожидания.

Comment: max и min  вообще плохие имена, они определены в системных заголовкак как макросы  (в WIndef.h), но здесь это не должно играть роли. Что быдет если завернуть max  и min в скобки?  По этой же причине using namespace std не стоит использовать - они там тоже есть.

Comment: Спасибо всем, что старались помочь мне с решением проблемы. Не знаю как и почему, но теперь минимум и максимум выводятся. Хотя я ничего не менял в программе с момента последнего тщетного ее запуска.